# Jackson : @JsonTypeId is not getting serialized properly when nested

Tags: jackson

I have a Zoo class which can contain animal of different types (Dog, ...) and has an animalType annotated with @JsonTypeId. The Dog class in turn can contain leash of different types (RopeLeash, ...) and has leashType annotated with @JsonTypeId. When i serialize the Zoo class using below method then the leashType gets set for animalType as well:

```
String zooJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(zoo);
```

Output is:

```
{"animal":{"leash":{"leashColor":"RED"},"leashType":"ROPE"},"animalType":"ROPE"}
```

Classes:

```
public class Zoo {
    @JsonTypeId
    private AnimalType animalType;
    private Animal animal; 

    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, 
            property = "animalType"
            )
    @JsonSubTypes({ 
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "CAT"),                
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "DOG")                
        })
    public void setAnimal(Animal animal) {
        this.animal = animal;
    }
   //Other getters and setters
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    @JsonTypeId
    private LeashType leashType;
    private Leash leash;
    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, 
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, 
            property = "leashType"
            )
    @JsonSubTypes({ 
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = RopeLeash.class, name = "ROPE")                
        })
    public void setLeash(Leash leash) {
        this.leash = leash;
    }
   //Other getters and setters
}

public class RopeLeash extends Leash {
    private String leashColor;
    //Getter and setter for leashColor
}
```

Is there something wrong in my annotation usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that Jackson does not support multi-level IDs. Posted this question in the Jackson site and here is the response:

> Multi-level type ids are not supported; a single id is required. No
>   support for multiple levels are planned to be used.

Link: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1462